# How to update values in SQL table by python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update the values for multiple tables like we have two tables temp and temp1. The temp table contains

[image]

and temp1 table contains

[image]

Temp1 is updated one so it should get updated in temp also like adb should be ghj & kkk should be 123.

Here is my code

```
merge= "merge "+str(a)+" Target using "+str(a)+"temp Source on Source."+str(pk_list[0])+" = Target."+str(pk_temp_list[0])+" when matched then update set Target."+str(col_list[i])+" =Source."+str(col_temp_list[i])+" when not matched by target then insert ("+str(col_list[i])+") values(Source."+str(col_temp_list[i])+");"
            print(merge)
            query=engine.execute(merge)
            print(query)
```

This is the error which I'm getting:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 't_creg', table 'TestDB.dbo.ttcmcs045100'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
> [SQL: merge ttcmcs045100 Target using ttcmcs045100temp Source on Source.t_creg = Target.t_creg when matched then update set Target.t_dsca =Source.t_dsca when not matched by target then insert (t_dsca) values(Source.t_dsca);]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)

Please help me out to solve this issuse.

Comment: The above looks *wide* open to injection attacks. You're injection dynamic object names without properly quoting them. The above is just dangerous.

Comment: The error is also telling you the problem; you are trying to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a row and assign `NULL` values to columns that aren't allowed to be `NULL`.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.